# automation - How to organize test cases, test objects and test suites?

Tags: automation, katalon-studio

I'm new to automation testing. I'm using Katalon to test an end-to-end feature that allows users to upload their files and get an analysis report. Here is a quick process flow:

Authentication -> click Upload Files -> click Add Files -> click Next -> click Submit

Is there any guideline for writing and arranging test cases and test suites? Now I'm writing test cases as follows:

- Test Case 1: **test** Authentication
- Test Case 2: **call** Test Case 1 -> **test** Upload Files
- Test Case 3: **call** Test Case 2 -> **test** Add Files
- Test Case 4: **call** Test Case 3 -> **test** Next
- Test Case 5: **call** Test Case 4 -> **test** Submit

Is it OK to write test cases like this or test cases should be independent from each other? For example,

- Test Case 1: **test** Authentication
- Test Case 2: **test** Upload Files
- Test Case 3: **test** Add Files
- Test Case 4: **test** Next
- Test Case 5: **test** Submit

In this case, I will put these Test Cases to a Test Suite so they will be executed sequentially:

Test Suite 1: call Test Case 1 -> call Test Case 2 -> call Test Case 3 -> call Test Case 4 -> call Test Case 5

Which one is more acceptable? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer keeping the tests separate and as independable as possible so I don't call test cases from another test case.

My tests are structured using Keywords, so they would look like:

1. myMethods.authetication(username, password)
2. myMethods.uploadFiles()
3. myMethods.addFiles()
4. myMethods.testNext()
5. myMethods.testSubmit()

However, since your tests consist of one click only (as far as I can tell), you could do something like this:

Step 1:

```
myMethods.authetication(username, password)
```

Step 2:

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable('id of the upload button')
WebUI.click('id of the upload button')
WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent('id of the upload button')
```

Step 3:

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable('id of the add files button')
WebUI.click('id of the add files button')
// verify expected condition
```

Step 4:

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable('id of the next button')
WebUI.click('id of the next button')
// verify expected condition
```

Step 5:

```
WebUI.waitForElementClickable('id of the submitbutton')
WebUI.click('id of the submit button')
// verify expected condition
```